# Reference lookup side column values based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I've got two worksheets, (a) contains rows which need to be dynamically updated based on a cell (ID), (b) contains over 10k product data by columns.

How do I achieve worksheet (a) to lookup data from worksheet (b) and based on the ID it picks up data from nearby columns. So when I change the ID to eg. 02 it will automatically populate above rows.

## Worksheet A

```
Name
Price
Qty
ID
```

## Worksheet B

```
ID | Name | Price | Qty
01 | Screw|  0.5  | 500
02 | Nail |  0.4  | 1000
03 | Cap  |  0.2  | 800
```

Comment: Seems like the `VLOOKUP()` function would do what you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes vlookup will work.

in each cell (except ID) you will need to put this formula:

=VLOOKUP(B1,WORKSHEETB!A1:D4,2,FALSE)

where "B1" is your ID and used to reference you table in worksheet B.

WORKSHEETB!A1:D4 is your table array (your table in worksheetB).

"2" is the column that you are referencing. Example Name is found in column 2 of that table array (doesn't matter where the table is located within the sheet name will always be column 2)

see images attached:

[image]

Comment: sorry forgot to change the ID #

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Name` is in Cell `A1`, `Price` is in Cell `A2`, `Qty` is in Cell `A3` and `ID` is in Cell `A4`, then:

- Cell B2 Formula: `=VLOOKUP(B4,'Worksheet B'!A:B,2,0)`
- Cell B3 Formula: `=VLOOKUP(B4,'Worksheet B'!A:C,3,0)`
- Cell B4 Formula: `=VLOOKUP(B4,'Worksheet B'!A:D,4,0)`